# Knitr - change the space between paragraphs in chunks failed for charts

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I wanted to decrease the space between chunks in my Rnw file (LateX+R+Knitr). I came across the following Rnw file that works for text output: https://gist.github.com/yihui/2760395#file-knitrout-parskip-rnw. If you have a chart it doesn't - the chart is moved too far upwards and a code as well as the chart overlap. Is there any possibilities to redefine knitrout in order to influence on output text not charts? I don't know how to attach pdf output but below is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

% change the space between paragraphs in chunks

\ifdefined\knitrout
  \renewenvironment{knitrout}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{-1in}
  }{
    \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
  }
\else
\fi

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the
lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the
lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

<<test>>=
set.seed(77)
1+1
(x <- rnorm(30))
@

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the
lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

<<fig.height=3>>=
plot(x)
@
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the
lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a smaller negative `\parskip`.  For example, this looks okay to me:

```
\ifdefined\knitrout
  \renewenvironment{knitrout}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{-0.5in}
  }{
    \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
  }
\else
\fi
```

The result: 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. May be it's possible to move text but figures.

Comment: Better is to use: -0.5em, but even that solution doesn't satisfy me. The whole problem will disappear if graphics and texts are in a different knitrout environments.But for a chunk there is a one knitrout.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43331/control-vertical-space-before-and-after-verbatim-environment).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=-1em \partopsep=-1em }
\makeatother
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Can you post before and after pictures?  On my system that looks the same as if I made no attempt to change the spacing.

Comment: This works if you do not want to space between paragraphs `(i.e \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}`. It doesn't work if you want to add space between paragraphs with for example `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}`